# With $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$ a measure space, $\mu$ nonatomic, if $0 < k < \mu(X)$, exists increasing sequence of sets with limit of measure $=k$?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Is the following claim true?

> Let $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu$ nonatomic. If $0 < k < \mu(X)$, there exists an increasing sequence $B_1, B_2, \dots \in \mathcal{B}$ (i.e., $B_1 \subset B_2 \subset \cdots $) with $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(B_n) = k$.

I'm honestly not sure if this is true, nor would I know how to prove this. I am willing to accept a source that cites this result and sketches out a proof as an answer to this question.

I do know that *if* there is an increasing sequence $B_1, B_2, \dots$ that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(B_n) = \mu(\lim_{n \to \infty}B_n)$. But that's the extent of my knowledge of this problem, as far as I know.

Please do not use the result that for every $c \in (0, \mu(X))$ that there exists a set $C$ with $\mu(C) = c$ due to $\mu$ being nonatomic.

Comment: What is your definition of non-atomic measure?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven For each $A \in \mathcal{B}$ with positive measure, there is a $B \subset A$ with $0 < \mu(B) < \mu(A)$.

Comment: I do not quite see how to do it without the fact you mention in the end. So I just proved that fact form scratch, hope that is also fine. Otherwise.... sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Fix a measurable set $A$ (wlog $m(A)<\infty$). We want to show that this set contains arbitrary small measurable sets. As $m$ is non-atomic, there exists $B\subseteq A$ such that $0<m(B)<m(A)$. We define
$$ B_1:= \begin{cases} B,& m(B)\leq m(A)/2,\\ A\setminus B,& \text{else}. \end{cases} $$
Recursively, we can define this way a sequence $(B_n)_{n\geq 1}$ such that $m(B_n)\leq 2^{-n} m(A)$. Thus, $A$ contains sets of arbitrary small (positive) measure.

2.) Now we define
$$ P:=\{ (B_n)_{n\geq 1}  \ : \ A \subseteq B_{n+1} \subseteq B_n, \ m(B_n) \leq m(B_{n+1} \leq k \} $$
with the partial order
$$ (B_n)_{n\geq 1} \leq (C_n)_{n\geq 1}  \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \forall n\geq 1: B_n \subseteq C_n. $$
It is easy to check that this poset satisfies the assumptions of Zorn's lemma (for the upper bound, just take the union) and thus, there exists a maximal element $(D_n)_{n\geq 1}$. By the maximality of this element follows that $m(\bigcup_{n\geq 1} D_n)=k$, otherwise consider $(E_n)_{n\geq 1}$ with $E_n:=\bigcup_{n\geq 1} D_n \cup F$ where $F\subseteq A\setminus \bigcup_{n\geq 1} D_n$ with $0<m(F) < k - m(\bigcup_{n\geq 1} D_n)$ (such a $F$ exists due to 1.)).

Hence, we have found $C\subseteq A$ such that $m(C)=k$. Now pick a nested sequence $(G_n)_{n\geq 1}$ such that $G_1\subseteq C$ and such that $m(G_n)= 2^{-n}m(C)$. Then $B_n:= C \setminus G_n$ does the job (it is increasing and you converge to the right limit).